# Apollo-Client | No result from query when using certain fields

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to use apollo-client in my react-native app but for some reason I can only get results from queries when I use certain fields.

Here's my first query :

```
`query RootQueryType($page: Int!) {
                    events(page: $page) {
                        title
                    }
                }`
```

Working perfectly in RN and GraphiQL but as soon as I add or use an other field than `title` I don't get any result from the query in RN. It's working perfectly in GraphiQL and there's no error at all.

For example :

```
`query RootQueryType($page: Int!) {
                    events(page: $page) {
                       description
                    }
                }`
```

Here's my event type :

```
const EventType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'EventType',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        title: { type: GraphQLString },
        category: { type: GraphQLString },
        description: { type: GraphQLString },
        terminated: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
        coverUrl: { type: GraphQLString },
        startDate: { type: GraphQLString },
        endDate: { type: GraphQLString },
        price: { type: GraphQLFloat },
        website: { type: GraphQLString },
        ticketsUrl: { type: GraphQLString },
        geometry: { type: GraphQLString },
        participantsCount: { type: GraphQLInt },
        participants: {
            type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
            resolve(parentValue) {
                return Event.findParticipants(parentValue.id);
            }
        }
    })
});
```